# Unity Playlist in order

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio-player

I've got a playlist which shuffles the songs, however I want to either play them in order or shuffle.
Any help will be appreciated :)

public class Music : MonoBehaviour {

```
public AudioClip[] clips;
private AudioSource audiosource;

void Start()
{
    audiosource = FindObjectOfType<AudioSource>();
    audiosource.loop = false;
}

void Update()
{
    if(!audiosource.isPlaying)
    {

        audiosource.clip = GetRandomClip();
        audiosource.Play();
    }
}

private AudioClip GetRandomClip()
{
    return clips[Random.Range(0, clips.Length)];
}

private void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
}
```

}

Comment: how/when does clips get populated in the first place?

Comment: to answer my own question: just drag/drop tracks into the array in unity editor

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your problem, isn't it as simple as that ?

```
public class Music : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public AudioClip[] clips;
    private AudioSource audiosource;
    public bool randomPlay = false;
    private int currentClipIndex = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        audiosource = FindObjectOfType<AudioSource>();
        audiosource.loop = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(!audiosource.isPlaying)
        {
            AudioClip nextClip;
            if (randomPlay)
            {
                nextClip = GetRandomClip();
            }
            else
            {
                nextClip = GetNextClip();
            }
            currentClipIndex = clips.IndexOf(nextClip);
            audiosource.clip = nextClip;
            audiosource.Play();
        }
    }

    private AudioClip GetRandomClip()
    {
        return clips[Random.Range(0, clips.Length)];
    }

    private AudioClip GetNextClip()
    {
        return clips[(currentClipIndex + 1) % clips.Length)];
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer did not work. It returned several errors. 
I have revised your script and tested it with Unity 2018.2.12f1.

This should be added to an empty game object, with an audio source component. 
Drag and drop audio clips to the clips field to create the list.

```
public bool randomPlay = false; // checkbox for random play
public AudioClip[] clips;
private AudioSource audioSource;
int clipOrder = 0; // for ordered playlist

void Start () {
    audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
    audioSource.loop = false;
}

void Update () {
    if (!audioSource.isPlaying) {
        // if random play is selected
        if (randomPlay == true) {
            audioSource.clip = GetRandomClip ();
            audioSource.Play ();
            // if random play is not selected
        } else {
            audioSource.clip = GetNextClip ();
            audioSource.Play ();
        }
    }
}

// function to get a random clip
private AudioClip GetRandomClip () {
    return clips[Random.Range (0, clips.Length)];
}

// function to get the next clip in order, then repeat from the beginning of the list.
private AudioClip GetNextClip () {
    if (clipOrder >= clips.Length - 1) {
        clipOrder = 0;
    } else {
        clipOrder += 1;
    }
    return clips[clipOrder];
}

void Awake () {
    DontDestroyOnLoad (transform.gameObject);
}
```